# https redirecting to http

Tags: iis-7, arr, server-farm

We're using Microsoft ARR with offloading for managing our new web farm. The site is split into 2 applications. 1 holds the content management system and the other holds the purchasing system. These need to be separated for functionality purposes. The link connecting the 2 has https in the url but when the page loads it's on http. If you manually change the url in the address bar to https then it works so why would it be loading the link as http in the first place?

Hopefully this isn't too vague. I am but a humble programmer and server configuration isn't my area of expertise.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your ARR rewrite rule is probably sending to HTTP, check your ARR settings.

Comment: I suspect this is the case but don't know enough about it to configure it correctly. Currently there is is one rule with the patter .* condition set to HTTP_HOST and the domain name and redirects to the server farm using HTTP, which I suspect is the problem. How can I configure it to have separate rule for HTTPS. I have no clue when it comes to regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with similar difficulties found the solution for creating the HTTPS rule in following article:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/10/16/iis-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy-and-load-balancing-solution-for-o365-exchange-online-in-a-hybrid-configuration.aspx